# Cyclotomic completion of $\mathbb{Z}[q]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and let $\Phi_S = \{ \Phi_n(q) \mid n \in S \}$ where $\Phi_n(q)$ denotes de $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial. Denote by $\Phi_S^*$ de multiplicative subset associated to $\Phi_S$ ordered by divisibility. Then we can consider the completion 
$$\mathbb{Z}[q]^S = \varprojlim_{f \in \Phi_S^*} \mathbb{Z}[q]/(f)$$

> Why when considering $S = \mathbb{N}$ we get $$\mathbb{Z}[q]^{\mathbb{N}} = \varprojlim_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}[q]/((q)_n)$$ where
>   $$(q)_n = (1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^n)$$

The question really is why $f(q) \in \Phi_{\mathbb{N}}^*$ is of the form $(q)_n$ for some $n$. I believe I could answer this question myself with some better knowledge of the properties of cyclotomic polynomials, so if someone could point me out and article or something where this things are explained, I'd be grateful too. Thank you!

**Edit**: I believe I didn't put much thought into this question. Obviously it is not true that every $f \in \Phi_{\mathbb{N}}^*$ can be written as $(q)_n$ for some $n \geq 0$. What is true however, is that for each polynomial $f \in \Phi_{\mathbb{N}}^*$, there is some $n$ such that $f \mid (q)_n$. That means that the set $\{(-1)^n(q)_n \mid n \geq 0\}$ is cofinal in $\Phi_{\mathbb{N}}^*$, and hence 
$$\mathbb{Z}[q]^S = \varprojlim_{f \in \Phi_S^*} \mathbb{Z}[q]/(f) \cong \varprojlim_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}[q]/((q)_n)$$
as desired.

Comment: If you understand the answer to your question, you can post it as an actual answer. (Or are you still asking readers why for all $f\in\Phi_{\Bbb N}^{\ast}$ there exists an $n$ such that $f\mid (q)_n$?)

Comment: @anon Is it really ok if I post it as an answer? Regarding your question, I haven't come up with a proof about that yet, but I believe that if $f$ is a product of say, $s$ cyclotomic polynomials, taking as $n$ the biggest index in the product $\Phi_{r_1}\dots \Phi_{r_s}$ should work.

Comment: Yes it is okay, and yes your belief is correct (so you pretty much have come up with a proof, or at least the ingredients of one). | Edit: you do want to be careful, because even if you pick $n$ as the biggest index, you can't control the multiplicity of the cyclotomic polynomials of lower index...

Comment: @anon That's right, I only considered the case with multiplicity one for each factor. If the multiplicities are $l_1, \dots l_r$, does $\max_{i,j} \{ r_i^{l_j}\}$ work? I need to rewrite the proof, hoping it doesn't get too tedious D: